# $a,b,c: ab+bc+ca=3abc$. Prove that: $7(a+b+c)+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{8a^2+bc}$

Tags: inequality

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c>0: ab+bc+ca=3abc$. Prove that: $$7(a+b+c)+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 2\left(\sqrt{8a^2+bc}+\sqrt{8b^2+ca}+\sqrt{8c^2+ab}+3\right)$$
> The source is unknown.

Here is my attempt:
Give $(a,b,c)\rightarrow \left(\dfrac{1}{a},\dfrac{1}{b},\dfrac{1}{c}\right)$. The problem becomes : $$7(ab+bc+ca)+3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}\ge 6+2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{bc(a^2+8bc)}$$
for $a,b,c>0: a+b+c=3$.

I used AM-GM as: $$6+2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{bc(a^2+8bc)}\le 6+\frac{17(ab+bc+ca)+a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}=9+5(ab+bc+ca)$$
But: $$7(ab+bc+ca)+3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}\ge 9+5(ab+bc+ca)$$ does not hold for $a=b\rightarrow 0$.

Also, by C-S: $$6+2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{bc(a^2+8bc)}\le 6+2\sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)(9+6(ab+bc+ca))}$$
and: $$7(ab+bc+ca)+3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}\ge 6+2\sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)(9+6(ab+bc+ca))}$$ does not hold for $a=b\rightarrow 0$

I check stronger, notice that $abc\ge 1$: $$7(a+b+c)-3\ge 2\left(\sqrt{8a^2+bc}+\sqrt{8b^2+ca}+\sqrt{8c^2+ab}\right)$$
Due to symmetric inequality, I set $b=c=x\ge \frac{2}{3}$ the given condition: $2xa+x^2=3ax^2\implies a=\frac{x}{3x-2}$. By software, the following inequality is true: $$7(2x+\frac{x}{3x-2})-3\ge 2\left(\sqrt{8\left(\frac{x}{3x-2}\right)^2+x^2}+2\sqrt{8x^2+x\frac{x}{3x-2}}\right)$$
[See here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=7%5C%2840%292x%2B%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29x%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%293x-2%5C%28125%29%5C%2841%29-3-2%5Cleft%5C%2840%29%5Csqrt%5C%28123%298Power%5B%5Cleft%5C%2840%29%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29x%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%293x-2%5C%28125%29%5Cright%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29%2B2%5Csqrt%5C%28123%298Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2Bx%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29x%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%293x-2%5C%28125%29%5C%28125%29%5Cright%5C%2841%29%3E0)

I hope someone can give me a hint to solve the OP as well as stronger version (in case it is really true). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Schur and Muirhead $$a+b+c+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\geq2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab}.$$
Also, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{8a^2+bc}\leq\sum_{cyc}\left(2a+\sqrt{bc}+\frac{8a^2+bc}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}\right).$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a+\sqrt{bc})\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{8a^2+bc}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{18abc}{ab+ac+bc}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^2+bc)\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{8a^4+b^2c^2}{2a^2+bc}+\frac{18a^2b^2c^2}{a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(4a^2+bc-\frac{8a^4+b^2c^2}{2a^2+bc}\right)\geq\frac{18a^2b^2c^2}{a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{2a^2+bc}\geq\frac{3abc}{a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2},$$ which is true by C-S and AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{a}{2a^2+bc}=\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{1}{2a+\frac{bc}{2}}\geq\tfrac{9}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(2a+\frac{bc}{a}\right)}\geq\tfrac{9}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{ac}{b}+\frac{bc}{a}\right)}=\tfrac{3abc}{a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2}.$$

Comment: The AM-GM idea using $2a+\sqrt{bc}$ is very nice!

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang  I think, your inequality is  very nice.