# Find a nice proof for an elegant problem.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw, buffalo-way

> **Question.** For any $a,b,c>0$ then prove that$$\frac{\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}}{bc}+\frac{\sqrt{5b^2+4ca}}{ca}+\frac{\sqrt{5c^2+4ab}}{ab}\le \frac{9}{4}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{abc}+\frac{a+b+c}{ab+bc+ca}\right).$$
> Source: unknown.

**Context.**

A long time ago, I saw it in a group Facebook. I've found the original link but it is no longer viewable.

I want to find some elegant proofs for this nice problem. It would be great if there's an AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz ideas.

Firstly, I verified it by multiply $abc$ and the problem becomes $$4\left(a\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}+b\sqrt{5b^2+4ac}+c\sqrt{5c^2+4ab}\right)\le 9\left(a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{abc(a+b+c)}{ab+bc+ca}\right). $$
Naturally, we can eliminate the square root of left side by C-S.

It's $$a\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}+b\sqrt{5b^2+4ac}+c\sqrt{5c^2+4ab}\le \sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(5a^2+5b^2+5c^2+4ab+4bc+4ca)} \tag{1}$$$$a\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}+b\sqrt{5b^2+4ac}+c\sqrt{5c^2+4ab}\le \sqrt{(a+b+c)(5a^3+5b^3+5c^3+12abc)} \tag{2}$$
I checked $a=b=0.99; c=1$ so $(1)$ and $(2)$ lead to wrong inequalities.

Also, we can come up with (in some ways) an isolated fuding inspired by [RiverLi's idea for similar inequality.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748306/abbccaabc-4-prove-sum-frac2-sqrtab-sqrtabc-fraca2b2c2/4814413#4814413)

Indeed, we may find an estimate$$\color{black}{\frac{xb+xc+ya}{ab+bc+ca}+\frac{9a}{bc}\ge 4\frac{\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}}{bc} .}$$
In cases there's exist $(x,y),$ I hope the solver will give your motivation to obtain that approach.

That's all what I've done so far. Thank you for your contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Remark.*

The following proof is inspired by Michael Rozenberg's idea. See [topic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704343/a-b-c-abbcca-3abc-prove-that-7abc3-sqrt3abc-ge-2-sum-cyc-sqrt)

The motivation is based on $\sum_{sym}\dfrac{b+c}{2(ab+bc+ca)}\ge \sum_{sym} \dfrac{1}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}.$

**Proof.**

We may use AM-GM for $2a+\sqrt{bc}$ as $$2\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}=2\sqrt{\frac{5a^2+4bc}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}\cdot(2a+\sqrt{bc})}\le \frac{5a^2+4bc}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}+2a+\sqrt{bc}=4a+\frac{5bc+a^2}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}.$$
Also, $$2a+\sqrt{bc}\ge 2a+\dfrac{2bc}{b+c}=\dfrac{2(ab+bc+ca)}{b+c}.$$
Thus, we obtain $$4\frac{\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}}{bc}\le \frac{8a}{bc}+\frac{(b+c)\left(\dfrac{a^2}{bc}+5\right)}{ab+bc+ca}.$$Notice that $$(b+c)\left(\dfrac{a^2}{bc}+5\right)=(ab+ac+bc)\frac{a}{bc}+5(b+c)-a.$$
And we see $$\frac{5(b+c)-a}{ab+bc+ca}+\frac{9a}{bc}\ge 4\frac{\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}}{bc} . $$
Take cyclic sum on it, we get desired inequality. Equality holds iff $a=b=c>0.$

Answer (score -1):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}\leq\frac{9}{4}\left(a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{abc(a+b+c)}{ab+ac+bc}\right).$$
Now, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{5a^2+4bc}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(5a^4+4a^2bc+2ab\sqrt{(5a^2+4bc)(5b^2+4ac)}\right)}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+4a^2bc)+2\sqrt{(ab+ac+bc)\sum_{cyc}ab(5a^2+4bc)(5b^2+4ac)}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+4a^2bc)+2\sqrt{(ab+ac+bc)\sum_{cyc}ab(5a^2+4bc)(5b^2+4ac)}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{81}{16}\left(a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{abc(a+b+c)}{ab+ac+bc}\right)^2,$$ which is true, but my proof of this statement  is not so nice yet.

Comment: I got a very strange message: "$-100$ several voting was reversed" All these for right solutions!  Why up-voting for my solution was deleted? Something is not true in my solution? What happens here?

Comment: I upvote your answer. By the way, I got the same situation. Some down-voter is destroying our site.

Comment: Do you mean *serial* voting? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829